# Alternated IP config does not work on Win10 like it is setup in the config

Tags: networking, router, dhcp

I do have to use a win10 pc to remote a system that shall work even if the router isn't working any more as the pc is used for remote a system where damage is possible if you are not able to remote the system.

Normal is dhcp a good solution for the system and I like to use it as long it is possible but in case of the DHCP-Server isn't workin any more I like to use alternativ config for the ipv4 as than this wouldn't do anything to the system itself and Internet isn't important as loosing control over the remoted system as without the server there is no internet working at all but the home LAN should work allways.

At the moment I get even with the setup of IP=192.168.2.142/255.255.255.0 allways when there is no dhcp the 169.254.22.54/16 what is not use full at all.

Does someone know what is wrong with Win10 and alternated IPconfig

Comment: are you asking why MS uses 169.254 addresses when a DHCP server is not available and the NIC is set to use DHCP?

Answer (score 0):

I found that after 3 Minutes ore some how time the alterneted config gets to work. How may I manage this to be more quick comming up.

Did not recognise this but it worked after I did finish my question in here and so I was very surprised about the change.

Comment: it is very crazy as it worked twice but not now - Should work ever ever.

Comment: Problem is solved - after Softwareupdate of Win10 I've set up a fixed IP working.

Answer (score 0):

Windows must ensure that DHCP server is not accessible before alteriative settings applied. This process takes from ~2 to ~3.5 minute, depends on OS version. During this process temporary APIPA address is used.

---

But I do not see the reason for to use dynamic address in your case. Edit DHCP server's address scope and decrease its range slightly. Then set your station to static address usage, in the same subnet but out of the scope range, and set gate/DNS addresses to ones provided by the router to the DHCP clients.

Now the station will be independent. It will act normally when your router both works and hangs. The only point - if you change some router's settings which affects the parameters provided to clients via DHCP then adjust your station settings.